# React combine two queries

Tags: javascript

What I want is to mixed the geoCode of location and people, how can I achieve that?

```
const calculate = (location, people) => {
   let geoCode = {}
    const peoples = people.map((people) = {
         return {
             geoCode: {
               latitude: a.geoCode.latitude,
               longitude: a.geoCode.longitude,
             }
         }
         return { //this is for location
             geoCode: {
               latitude: location[0].address.geoCode.latitude,
               longitude: location[0].address.geoCode.longitude,
             }
         }

     console.log(peoples)
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. What is your output meant to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return two objects from a `map`. You should merge the properties of `location` and `people` into a single object and then return that object. From your code I am assuming that both `people` and `location` have `geocode`.

```js
const people = [{
    name: "People1",
    latitude: 111,
    longitude: 111,
  },
  {
    name: "People2",
    latitude: 222,
    longitude: 222,
  },
  {
    name: "People3",
    latitude: 333,
    longitude: 333,
  },
];

const loc = [{
  address: {
    geoCode: {
      latitude: 123,
      longitude: 345,
    }
  }
}];

const calculate = (location, people) => {
  let geoCode = {}
  const peoples = people.map((item) => {
    return {
      ...item,
      geoCode: {
        latitude: location[0].address.geoCode.latitude,
        longitude: location[0].address.geoCode.longitude,
      }
    };
  });

  console.log(peoples);
}

const res = calculate(loc, people);
```